# iPhone UIImage overlap render bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I've come across a strange render bug on iPhone OS 3.0...

I have two images. One is a non-transparent PNG that is predominately black with a white gradient fading upward.

The second is a transparent PNG with translucent clouds.

When I overlay the two using UIImageView, the intersection of the clouds and white gradient triggers a render bug that causes a rather odd looking graphical glitch that removes all opacity from the image on top (in this case the clouds), and causes the glitched portion of the image to render on top of all layers in the current view (including ones it is technically underneath).

It only occurs at the intersection of the two portions of the images. So typically only a very small block is experiencing the error while the rest of the images render normally.

Has anyone seen this and does anyone have a fix? I want to check before I move on to Core Animation which will hopefully address the problem (since I imagine that CA or even OpenGL is more apt to handle overlapping alpha channels).

Screenshot found here:

http://www.jasconi.us/glitch.jpg

You can see the intersect of the two images at the lower right.

Comment: Use the organizer tool in XCode to get screenshots from the device, if you want to include them.

Comment: UIImageView uses a CALayer to display its image (which in turn uses OpenGL).

Comment: Wow, the crazy thing is that even when I use the organizer it doesn't capture the bug.

I may send this in to Apple. Completely weird/annoying glitch... this is iPhone OS 3.0 fyi.

Comment: Try to press and hold the button on top of the device and then press the home button while holding the top button. This will take a screenshot and place the image in your photo library. Then you can transfer the image back to your computer through iPhoto. Then you can post it here. Would definitely help to see the issue.

Comment: I'll do that first thing tomorrow morning. Don't have my connector at home.

Comment: And sadly that technique doesn't work either. As soon as the screen makes that flashbulb flash the bug goes away. I'm going to see if I can take a picture with my cellphone.

Comment: OK here's the link to the screenshot... http://www.jasconi.us/glitch.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, this seems to be a bug in Apple's code. I would report it to Apple and wait for a fix.

In the meantime, you can try to implement the same functionality in Core Animation or OpenGL in the hope that the bug is in the higher-level UIImageView, but since the UIImageView itself uses Core Animation, it's possible that this bug is simply unavoidable until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're displaying them using UIImageView?  If so, have you set opaque to NO on the transparent view?

Comment: Yes. The layer in question is certainly transparent because there are other images behind it higher up on the screen (not pictured) that present well.

Comment: I'm probably going to go with Ben S. here. Based on the fact that even the Organizer can't snag a photo of it, this appears to be a very low level presentation glitch that I will have to go to Apple about. Luckily it's happening in a feature that is not mission critical so, woo!